# Is it just me...or is android honeycomb 3.0 emulator really slow?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

Well? I've tried increasing the RAM size of the emulator to 1024 MB and there was little improvement on the speed, however, it's still unusable. It has the speed of a turtle.

Anyone got better ideas to make it faster? Is there something I'm not doing correctly?

Comment: What spec PC do you have?  (I seem to remember some other guy asking this question a while back and his phone looked more powerful than the PC he was developing on!)

Comment: It's an asus laptop with intel core i3 processor... :D I'm developing stuff in ubuntu 10.10.. Yes, I heard testing on the actual device is much faster... I have a device, but I don't want to test on it everytime small changes are made that's just tedious

Comment: Testing on the device is *far* less tedious than the emulator. You can still debug it properly, it doesn't behave incorrectly like the emulator can. I'm not aware of any downsides at all, other than that you have to actually have the device (ie you're not emulating a device with a larger/smaller screen, extra hardware etc).

Comment: @황현정: `Is there something I'm not doing correctly?`: what have you been doing? is there any particular part of the development process that is slow (e.g. booting up the device, etc)? or is it just UI lag? why do you think testing on a device is more tedious (maybe you need a large desk and a tablet stand, or maybe you're plugging the cable the wrong way)? In any case, what have you been doing that you particularly feels can be done better?

Comment: There is an old adage that you need at least 10x more powerful computer to emulate some system over another system, which is quite true in the case of Android emulator as it emulates an ARM CPU on x86 CPU and most Android devices nowadays have crazy hardwares that almost closely matches their desktop counterpart.

Comment: Emulator performance is being actively worked on — see the Google I/O session on developer tools for more on that.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the android developer [documentation regarding 3.0 emulator performance](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/optimizing-for-3.0.html#Setup). Scroll down to `About Emulator Performance`.

Copied tip for convenience:

> Tip: To improve the startup time for the emulator, enable snapshots for the AVD when you create it with the SDK and AVD Manager (there's a checkbox in the AVD creator to Enable snapshots). Then, start the AVD from the AVD manager and check Launch from snapshot and Save to snapshot. This way, when you close the emulator, a snapshot of the AVD state is saved and used to quickly relaunch the AVD next time. However, when you choose to save a snapshot, the emulator will be slow to close, so you might want to disable Save to snapshot after you've acquired an initial snapshot (after you close the AVD for the first time).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like everything 3.0 and beyond is slow for me.   Everything before that runs very fast in emulator for me.  However, I have an Intel integrated graphics card in my laptop.  When I turn 3D setting to "Application Settings," I get relatively decent performance from the emulator, at least when it starts up, but then when I try to start any app from the default main app menu (contacts, for example) I get launcher errors.  That happens for me on 3.0, 3.1 and 3.2.  The one thing I'm suspicious of is that I'm running 64-bit Java SDK.  Seem to be a number of posts out there related to 64-bit, but mostly they seem to be point to using 64-bit SDK with 32-bit Eclipse or vice versa, but in my tests, I am not even running Eclipse, haven't even reinstalled the ADT yet, just the Android SDK and created a few emulator instances.  Again, prior to 3.0 everything is fast.  3.0 and beyond not good, but A LOT better with graphics settings as I mentioned above.  If I could get past the launcher issues, I think I might be all set.  Oh, btw also, for 3.0 and beyond, I bumped the memory up to 1024.  I've tried increasing the heap for apps to double the default (from 48 to 96) but that doesn't seem to have alleviated my launcher problems.

Answer (score 0):

It is slow.  You can try creating a new Emulator with a smaller resolution.

Comment: I did... :D It improved but force close was so frequent. :(

Comment: I don't think I'll ever get past the hello world tutorial. :P 
I wanna know what Reto Meier could say about this.

Answer (score 0):

I remember someone at google I/O saying that the HoneyComb emulator will run really really slow due to hardware acceleration turned on.

The PC may use software rendering for OpenGL hence the bad performance. The almost everything you see on the HoneyComb screen is rendered using OpenGL ES.

감사합니다,

Reno